# Word that describes a situation in which irony or antithesis is used to convey a truth or impart wisdom

Tags: single-word-requests

I know there's a word for this, but despite my attempts on Google, I was unable to find the term I'm looking for. I know it's not a **paradox**, which is a statement or concept that appears to make sense but in fact contradicts itself.

What I'm looking for is a term to describe something like the following:

> Relaxation, then, is not an end...it is for the sake of activity.

This is from a text we're reading for class. The author talks about the Sabbath in the Jewish religion. I'm looking for a term to succinctly describe the fact that the irony of the sentence or the antithesis of "relaxation" and "activity" conveys a truth: that by engaging in periods of idleness, one is able to collect one's strength and engage in activity anew.

Note that **antithesis** by itself just refers to the use of two contradictory ideas in close proximity. The term I'm thinking of suggests that this antithesis is employed to impart wisdom in a poetic manner.

Comment: Can you broaden your request to allow for phrases beyond single words?

Comment: I'm not convinced that **paradox** doesn't apply here (informally). Also your own **irony** seems very apt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be an **epigram**: "A concise, clever, often paradoxical statement" ([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=epigram)).

Comment: Yep, I believe that's the word I was looking for. After reading more about epigrams online, I'm convinced it suits this well. Thank you.